# Help with Inflexion points of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this function: $P(x) = x^4 +cx^3 + \frac{x^2}{24}$ and i need to find for which values of c the function has:

a) two inflection points

b) one inflection point

c) does not have any inflection point

I already know that $P''(x) = 12x^2 + 6cx + \frac{1}{12}$

But i don't what to do after that for find the values of c.

I would appreciate if somebody can help me.

Comment: Are you familiar with the relation between the discriminant of a quadratic equation and its number of solutions?

Comment: I forget it, but i remembered now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivative is $P''(x)=12x^2+6cx+\frac{1}{12}$.

$P''(x)=0$ will give the $x$-coordinates of the inflection points.

If the equation $P''(x)=0$ has two solutions, there are two inflection points, if it has one, there is one inflection point, if it has none, there is no inflection point.

The number of solutions to $P''(x)=0$ can be determined using the discriminant, which is $D=b^2-4ac=36c^2-4$.

For $36c^2-4>0$, $P''(x)=0$ has two solutions. For $36c^2-4=0$, $P''(x)=0$ has one solution, for $36c^2-4<0$, $P''(x)=0$ has no solutions.

> Two solutions for $c<-\frac13 \vee c>\frac13$. One solution for $c=-\frac13 \vee c=\frac13$. No solutions for $-\frac13<c<\frac13$.

Comment: for an inflexion point must be $P''(x)=0$ and $P'''(x)\ne 0$ or higher derivatives

Answer (score 1):

solving the equation $12x^2+6cx+\frac{1}{12}=0$ we get
$x_1=-c/4+1/12\,\sqrt {9\,{c}^{2}-1}$
$x_2=-c/4-1/12\,\sqrt {9\,{c}^{2}-1}$ 
for the existence of the solutions it must be $9c^2-1\geq 0$
if we have the equal sign we get one inflexion point, if we have the $>$ sign we have two points in the case we have $<$ then we get no such point

Answer (score 1):

The inflection points are the roots of the second derivative.

$a)$ We want to have two separate inflection points, hence the second derivative must have two separate roots. As the second derivative of your function is a quadratic equation, hence we should form its $\Delta$, which for the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ we have $\Delta=\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$. Hence we conclude for your second derivative polynomial $\Delta=(6c)^2-4\times 12\times\frac{1}{12}=36c^2-4$.

Now you want your second derivative polynomial have two separate roots. Hence $\Delta>0$ and it means $c^2>\frac{4}{36}\Rightarrow c>\frac{2}{6}$ or $c<\frac{-2}{6}$.

$b)$ If you want your function to have one inflection point, then your second derivative function which is a quadratic polynomial must have only one root. In this case, $\Delta=0\Rightarrow c^2=\frac{4}{36}\Rightarrow c=\frac{2}{6}$ or $c=\frac{-2}{6}$.

$c)$ In this case the quadratic polynomial must have no real roots, hence $\Delta<0\Rightarrow c^2<\frac{4}{36}\Rightarrow \frac{-2}{6}<c<\frac{2}{6}$